# How to pull connected data from database into R Notebook in IBM DSX?

Tags: r, data-science-experience

I would like to reference a table in a database within an R notebook on DSX.

I have established a connection to my GreenPlum database and set up one table as a data asset in my project.  Within my R notebook, I have navigated to "Connections" and created a list with my credentials for the database:

```
credentials_1 <-list(database = "database",password = 
"password",sg_service_url = "https://sgmanager.ng.bluemix.net",port = 
"1111",host = "111.111.111.11",sg_gateway_id = "XXXXXXX_prod_ng",username = 
"username",sg_security_token = "XXXXXX",connection_path = 
"/analytics/ibm_test")
```

Next, I used a helper function using this [IBM Resource.](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/90a34943032a7fde0ced0530d976ca82)

```
getObjectStorageFile <- function(credentials) {
if(!require(httr)) install.packages('httr')
if(!require(RCurl)) install.packages('RCurl')
library(httr, RCurl)
auth_url <- paste(credentials[['sg_service_url']],'/v3/auth/tokens', sep= '')
auth_args <- paste('{"auth": {"identity": {"password": {"user": {"domain": {"id": ', credentials[['domain_id']],'},"password": ',
               credentials[['password']],',"name": ', credentials[['username']],'}},"methods": ["password"]}}}', sep='"')
auth_response <- httr::POST(url = auth_url, body = auth_args)
x_subject_token <- headers(auth_response)[['x-subject-token']]
auth_body <- content(auth_response)
access_url <- unlist(lapply(auth_body[['token']][['catalog']], function(catalog){
    if((catalog[['type']] == 'object-store')){
        lapply(catalog[['endpoints']], function(endpoints){
            if(endpoints[['interface']] == 'public' && endpoints[['region_id']] == credentials[['region']]) {
               paste(endpoints[['url']], credentials[['container']], credentials[['filename']], sep='/')}
        })
    }
})) 
data <- content(httr::GET(url = access_url, add_headers ("Content-Type" = "application/json", "X-Auth-Token" = x_subject_token)), as="text")
textConnection(data)
}
```

Note that I changed `auth_url <- ....'auth_url'` to be `auth_url <- ....'sg_service_url'` because my credentials inserted did not have an `auth_url` and that seemed to give an obvious error that the url was missing.  So I ran this function in the attempt to assign the result to data frame:

```
R.data.frame <- getObjectStorageFile(credentials_1)
head(R.data.frame)
```

The error I finally receive is: **"Error in handle_url(handle, url, ...): Must specify at least one of url or handle"**

I also tried the `setHadoopConfig` function within the [IBM Resource](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/90a34943032a7fde0ced0530d976ca82); however, this gave me another error for **The value of property fs.swift.service.keystone.tenant must not be null.**

My main question is which function I need to add a handle/url argument to?  I don't understand exactly what the helper function is doing, but I have a feeling that the auth_url object is not being assigned.

Comment: @A.J.Alger - thanks for sharing that - I think you may be right that Object Storage functions do not work with database connections.  
I have tried installing the R package referenced in your link; however, I am seeing that it's not available in my DSX notebook and R Studio: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dsxCoreUtilsR’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)`

Comment: Are you using DSX Local or on Cloud? The link in the comment above is from the documentation fro DSX local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect the GreenPlum database using the `RPostgreSQL` package.

Specifically, I needed to pass the host/port of my IBM Secure Gateway to the `dbConnect` function

```
library(RPostgreSQL) ## Load library

## Assign Credentials
drv <- dbDriver( "PostgreSQL" )
db <- "database_name"
host_db <- "cap-sg-prd-5.integration.ibmcloud.com" ### IBM SG host link
db_port <- 18999 ## IBM SG port as an integer
db_user <- "username"
db_password <- "password"

## Make the connection
conn <- dbConnect(drv, dbname=db, host=host_db, port=db_port, user=db_user, password=db_password)
```

If you do not know where the host/port of your Secure Gateway is, this may be found on BlueMix's Secure Gateway Dashboard.  First, go to "Integrate" in the BlueMix console, then select your Secure Gateway. Once in the dashboard, look under Destinations -> Settings (the gear icon), and the host and port are listed with "Cloud Host : Port".

Heads up, you may need to recreate your Secure Gateway destination if you created this before adding the connection to your project.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did a little digging on this one. To work with Greenplum on DSX you could install the PivotalR package. You install that with:

```
install.packages("PivotalR")
```

Then load it:

```
library(PivotalR)
```

From there, you can set up a database connection to your Greenplum database. According to the [documentation](https://pivotalsoftware.github.io/gp-r/#rpostgresql), it uses the RPostgreSQL package for that. Thus, a basic connection example might be:

```
drv <- dbDriver( "PostgreSQL" )
db <- 'myDatabase'  
host_db <- 'mydb1.example.com'  
db_port <- '98939'  
db_user <- 'henryviii'  
db_password <- 'happydays'

conn <- dbConnect(drv, dbname=db, host=host_db, port=db_port, user=db_user, password=db_password)
```

You then run an SQL query like:

```
myQuery<- dbSendQuery(conn, 'select some_column from my_table;')  
result <- fetch(myQuery)
```

Or, you could read the entire table:

```
dbReadTable(conn, 'my_table')
```

I've [written a quick run through on querying and writing data to a PostgreSQL database](https://www.compose.com/articles/connecting-r-and-compose-postgresql/) which could be useful for your case since you're working inside RStudio.

Comment: Thanks A.J.!  I'm still seeing a timeout error, I think because this package is not using the secure gateway ID and URL: `Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...): RS-DBI driver:... could not connect to server: Connection timed out`

Comment: That sounds more like a database error rather than the driver. Did you check your database connection?